# Why does the grunt-watch task say it is watching files/directories I have not specified in configuration?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I have the following Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    "use strict";

    grunt.initConfig({
        watch: {
            options: {
              livereload: true
            },
            css: {
                files: ["app.styles.css"]
            },
            js: {
              files: ["app/**/*.js"]
            },
            html: {
              files: ["index.html", "app/**/*.html"]
            }
        },
        connect: {
            server: {
                options: {
                    port: 9000,
                    hostname: "*",
                    livereload: true,
                    open: true
                }
            }
        },
        jshint: {
            files: ["app/**/*.js"]
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-jshint");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-watch");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-connect");

    grunt.registerTask("default", ["connect","watch"]);

};
```

I have the following structure in my application:

[image]

Note that app, bower_components, css and images are all on the same level.

When I run the task `grunt --verbose` I see that many more files/directories in my application are being watched including the bower_components and node_modules directories.

[image]

But I have not specified grunt to watch any of these files/directories. On top of that Grunt is not re-loading the application when I modify the css file specified in the configuration (app.styles.css). I thought that grunt only watched the files that I specified in Gruntfile.js which is what I want. Why is Grunt watching these extra files/directories and also not watching my app.styles.css file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[grunt-contrib-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-watch) uses a node package called [gaze](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gaze). It is gaze that builds the `watched` object of filepaths to watch and that makes the actual calls to `fs.watch`. The `watched` object is constructed of directory paths as keys with arrays of descendant file paths and subdirectory paths as values. A `watched` object with a single `scripts.js` file might look like the following:

```
{    
    "C:\\{{path_to_your_application_root}}\\app\\Scripts\\": [
        "C:\\{{path_to_your_application_root}}\\app\\Scripts\\script.js"
    ]
}
```

The interesting part is that when gaze is adding a filepath to the `watched` object, it looks for all directories that are siblings of that filepath and *adds those to the `watched` object also*!

The relevant code from the gaze source is as follows:

```
// add folders into the mix
var readdir = fs.readdirSync(dirname);
for (var j = 0; j < readdir.length; j++) {
    var dirfile = path.join(dirname, readdir[j]);
    if (fs.lstatSync(dirfile).isDirectory()) {
        helper.objectPush(this._watched, dirname, dirfile + path.sep);
    }
}
```

The result of this is that when your "index.html" filepath is found in your application root, all of the directories that live within your application root (app/, bin/, bower_components/, etc.) get added to the `watched` object also.

You can confirm this by removing "index.html" from your watch and you should no longer get all of those folder watchings in your verbose output.

Here is a [link](https://github.com/shama/gaze/issues/204) to a discussion of why the gaze library has this behavior.

As to why your "app.styles.css" is *not* watched: Are you perhaps missing a path to this file. I do not see "app.styles.css" in your application root. Presumably is under `css/`.

Answer (score 0):

So after coming back to this issue months later I finally figured out what I need to do to make it work. In Gruntfile.js you need to add `options: { livereload: true}` inside of the `css` property. I don't know why you need it in the `watch` property and then again inside the `css` property.

A minimalist working Gruntfile.js with a local development server and livereload is:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    "use strict";

    grunt.initConfig({
        watch: {
            options: {
                livereload: true
            },
            css: {
                files: ["css/**/*.css"],

                /*********************************** ADDED THIS ************************/
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            js: {
                files: ["app/**/*.js"]
            },
            html: {
                files: ["index.html", "app/**/*.html"]
            }
        },
        connect: {
            server: {
                options: {
                    port: 9000,
                    hostname: "*",
                    livereload: true,
                    open: true
                }
            }
        },
        jshint: {
            files: ["app/**/*.js"]
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-jshint");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-watch");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-connect");

    grunt.registerTask("default", ["connect", "watch"]);
};
```